# I'm getting Runtime Error : Segmentation Fault (SIGSEGV), why?

Tags: c

I am getting a runtime error in this and i can't seem to figure it out.
This is my code to reverse a string and change A to T and vice-versa and to change C to G and vice-versa,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

char* reverse(char *input)
{
    int len=strlen(input);
    char *rev=NULL;
    rev=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*len);
    int i,k=0;
    for(i=len-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        rev[k++]=input[i];
        if(rev[k-1]=='A')
            rev[k-1]='T';
        else if(rev[k-1]=='T')
            rev[k-1]='A';
        else if(rev[k-1]=='C')
            rev[k-1]='G';
        else if(rev[k-1]=='G')
            rev[k-1]='C';
    }
    rev[k]='\0';
    return rev;
}

int main()
{
    char *input=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*1000);
    scanf("%s",input);
    char *str =NULL;//(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*1000);
    str=reverse(input);
    printf("%s",input);
     free(input);
}
```

Comment: `for(i=len-1;i>=0;i++)`--> `for(i=len-1;i>=0;i--)` and why are you allocating memory for `str` in main when you are already allocating memory in `reverse()`

Comment: `str=reverse(input);` is leaking memory.

Comment: Made the required changes but i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I try your programme and it works for me. Just change the last printf into `printf("%s\n", str);` and `input = "ATGC"` before the call to reverse. It works fine and print CGAT.

Comment: in function: `main()`, the array `str[]` is being set, but never used.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) the expression `sizeof(char)` is (per the standard) always 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  Suggest remove that expression the call to `malloc()`  2) the returned type from any these functions is `void*` which can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting just clutters the code (and is error prone).  Suggest removing the cast.  3) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the `%s` input/format specifier, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer so a buffer overrun will not occur.  Such buffer overrun results in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: the posted code has a massive memory leak.  This can be fixed by inserting this statement: `free( str );`  just before returning from `main()`

Comment: suggest: print the input buffer before performing the `reverse`  Then add a new print statement After the call to `reverse()` to allow the user to verify the modified string

Comment: All the output streams are buffered.  So the output can sit in that buffer until the program ends.  To get immediate display on the terminal, either append a '\n' to the end of the format string (for instance of `printf()`) -or- follow the print operation with a call to `fflush( stdout )`  Note, the first method is preferred.

Answer (score 4):

You do not allocate enough memory to hold your reversed string:

```
int len=strlen(input);
...
rev=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*len);
...
rev[k]='\0';
```

You missed 1 extra byte for the terminating `\0`.

And by the way... Please don't cast the return value from `malloc` to a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you use `i++` instead of `i--` in the for loop. That means that the `for` loop never ends and `k` gets very very big and your `rev[k]` atempts to access values that it shouldnt.

Secondly, you do not need to allocate memory for `str`, because you allocate it in the function.

And you should allocate memory for one more char in the function as you will need if for `'\0'`.

Comment: Why should the for loop be infinite? Counting down from len-1 ... 0 is perfectly fine

Comment: He had it `++` instead of `--` .Must have edited it now.

Comment: Ah, I missed that fix. Of course you are right, then.